# Optimal way to get all duplicated rows in a polars dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

I want to filter all duplicated rows from a polars dataframe. What I've tried:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame([['1', '1', '1', '1'], ['7', '7', '2', '7'], ['3', '9', '3', '9']])
df
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 2        ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

df.filter(pl.all().is_duplicated())
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

This selects the first row, because it appears to go column-by-column and returns each row where all columns have a corresponding duplicate in the respective column - not the intended outcome.

Boolean indexing works:

```
df[df.is_duplicated(), :]
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But it leaves me wondering

- if this is indeed the only way to do it,
- if there's a way to use `.filter()` and expressions to achieve the same result
- if this is the most efficient way to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, the `is_duplicated` method will likely perform best.  Let's take a look at some alternative ways to accomplish this.  And we'll do some (very) non-rigorous benchmarking - just to see which ones perform reasonably well.

#### Some alternatives

One alternative is a `filter` statement with an `over` (windowing) expression on all columns.  One caution with windowed expressions - they are convenient, but can be costly performance-wise.

```py
df.filter(pl.count("column_1").over(df.columns) > 1)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Another alternative is a `groupby`, followed by a `join`.  Basically, we'll count the number of times that combinations of columns occur.  I'm using a `semi` join here, simply because I don't want to include the `count` column in my final results.

```py
df.join(
    df=df.groupby(df.columns)
    .agg(pl.count().alias("count"))
    .filter(pl.col("count") > 1),
    on=df.columns,
    how="semi",
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

#### Some (very) non-rigorous benchmarking

One way to see which alternatives perform reasonably well is to time the performance on a test dataset that might resemble the datasets that you will use.  For lack of something better, I'll stick to something that looks close to the dataset in your question.

Set `nbr_rows` to something that will challenge your machine. (My machine is a 32-core system, so I'm going to choose a reasonably high number of rows.)

```py
import numpy as np
import string

nbr_rows = 100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": np.random.choice(1_000, nbr_rows,),
        "col2": np.random.choice(1_000, nbr_rows,),
        "col3": np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), nbr_rows,),
        "col4": np.random.choice(1_000, nbr_rows,),
    }
)
print(df)
```

```
shape: (100000000, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 955  ┆ 186  ┆ j    ┆ 851  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 530  ┆ 199  ┆ d    ┆ 376  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 109  ┆ 609  ┆ G    ┆ 115  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 886  ┆ 487  ┆ d    ┆ 479  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 837  ┆ 406  ┆ Y    ┆ 60   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 467  ┆ 769  ┆ P    ┆ 344  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 548  ┆ 372  ┆ F    ┆ 410  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 379  ┆ 578  ┆ t    ┆ 287  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Now let's benchmark some alternatives.  Since these may or may not resemble your datasets (or your computing platform), I won't run the benchmarks multiple times.  For our purposes, we're just trying to weed out alternatives that might perform very poorly.

##### Alternative: `is_duplicated`

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
df[df.is_duplicated(),:]
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

```
>>> print(end - start)
7.834882180000932
```

Since the `is_duplicated` method is provided by the Polars API, we can be reasonably assured that it will perform very well.  Indeed, this should be the standard against which we compare other alternatives.

##### Alternative: `filter` using an `over` (windowing) expression

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df.filter(pl.count("col1").over(df.columns) > 1)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

```
>>> print(end - start)
18.136289041000055
```

As expected, the `over` (windowing) expression is rather costly.

##### Alternative: `groupby` followed by a `join`

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df.join(
    df=df.groupby(df.columns)
    .agg(pl.count().alias("count"))
    .filter(pl.col("count") > 1),
    on=df.columns,
    how="semi",
)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

```
>>> print(end - start)
9.419006452999383
```

Somewhat better ... but not as good as using the `is_duplicated` method provided by the Polars API.

##### Alternative: `concat_str`

Let's also look at an alternative suggested in another answer.  To be fair, @FBruzzesi did say "I am not sure this is optimal by any means".  But let's look at how it performs.

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df.filter(pl.concat_str(df.columns, sep='|').is_duplicated())
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

```
>>> print(end - start)
37.238660977998734
```

### Edit

##### Additional Alternative: `filter` and `is_duplicated`

We can also use `filter` with `is_duplicated`.  Since `df.is_duplicated()` is not a column in the DataFrame when the filter is run, we'll need to wrap it in a [`polars.lit`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.lit.html) Expression.

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df.filter(pl.lit(df.is_duplicated()))
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

```
>>> print(end - start)
8.115436136999051
```

This performs just as well as using `is_duplicated` and boolean indexing.

Did this help?  If nothing else, this shows some different ways to use the Polars API.

Comment: Thank you for the multiple alternatives along with benchmarks.
The only "concern" is that the implementations using the filter method seem to be the slowest ones. I believe that OP, as myself, would like to use method chaining most of the time. Using the join method may be the compromise between performance and method chaining.

Comment: You can use a filter with the is_duplicated as well.  (I actually tested that, but thought that the post was getting way too long as it was.)  I'll edit my answer to include that option.

Comment: Added (at the bottom).  Using a filter will run just as fast as using boolean indexing.  And to your point, the syntax if preferable.

Comment: When you want to verify duplicates with a subset of columns on a chain of expressions, using is_duplicated() is currently not possible. In this case, the filter()+over() option enables this feature, is convenient, clean and concise.

I don't know what is the difference in performance between the groupBy()+join() solution and the filter()+over() solution in your (reader) particular use case. But unless this is the most critical part and bottleneck of your app, and you have evidence that there is a very significant difference in performance, I'd suggest that you favor the more clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the optimal way really is:

`df.filter(df.is_duplicated())`

We have to be aware that Polars have `is_duplicated()` methods in the expression API and in the DataFrame API, but for the purpose of visualizing the duplicated lines we need to evaluate each column and have a consensus in the end if the column is duplicated or not.

The `df.is_duplicated()` will return a vector with boolean values,
It looks like this:

```py
In []: df.is_duplicated()
Out[]: 
shape: (4,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
    false
    true
    false
    true
]

In []:
```

Then leveraging our expression API I think we can do this:

```py
In []: df = pl.DataFrame([['1', '1', '1', '1'], ['7', '7', '2', '7'], ['3', '9', '3', '9']])
    ...: df
Out[]: 
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 3        │
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
│ 1        ┆ 2        ┆ 3        │
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
In []: df.filter(df.is_duplicated())
Out[]: 
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

And then for subseting:

```py
In []: df.filter(df.select(["column_0", "column_1"]).is_duplicated())
Out[]: 
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 3        │
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
│ 1        ┆ 7        ┆ 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Any other way for me seems to be trying to hack the API, I wish we had a way to "fold" the boolean columns we get by the expressions
`df.filter(pl.col("*").is_duplicated())`
`df.filter(pl.all().is_duplicated())`

It is funny, because look at this:

```py
In []: df.select(pl.all().is_duplicated())
Out[]: 
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ bool     ┆ bool     ┆ bool     │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ true     ┆ true     ┆ true     │
│ true     ┆ true     ┆ true     │
│ true     ┆ false    ┆ true     │
│ true     ┆ true     ┆ true     │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

This is what happens when we use `is_duplicated()` as expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this: "I wish we had a way to "fold" the boolean columns we get by the expressions", but I believe there are options to do what you meant: (1): `df.select(pl.all(pl.col('*').is_duplicated()))` works horizontally, but its usefulness is debatable, since the duplicates are still evaluated vertically per column before the horizontal `pl.all()`. (2): `df.select(pl.struct(pl.col('*')).is_duplicated())` is probably what you want, since the rows are first combined horizontally in the `struct` before `.is_duplicated()` is called.

Comment: I've never used `pl.struct` before, I'll try it out thank you. And I had the same Issue you meant using `pl.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is optimal by any mean but you could concatenate all rows and check for duplicates, namely:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [["1", "1", None, "1"], ["7", "7", None, "7"], ["3", None, None, None]],
    schema=["a", "b", "c"],
)

df.filter(
    pl.concat_str(pl.col(["a", "b", "c"]).fill_null("null")).is_duplicated()
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 7   ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ 7   ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Caveat: `fill_null("null")` - without this, all rows containing `null` would be treated the same. This means, however, if you have the string `"null"` appearing in your data, it will be treated identically to an actual `null`-value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is much more expensive than other options, but it is good to have it here for completeness' sake. I submitted an edit to account for `null`s.